# Fallo al actualizar con AJAX y Laravel

Tags: laravel

Me borra siempre el primero y cuando no hay ningún registro en la tabla con status=0 me devuelve error.

**Route con los que me llevo los datos a un foreach de la vista**

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
        $presupuestos = Presupuesto::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->where('status', 0);
        return view('admin.index', compact('presupuestos'));
    })->name('admin');
```

**Aquí el foreach en la vista**

```
  @foreach ($presupuestos as $presupuesto)
      <div class="row notificaNaranja dato_Naranja">
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="">
            <i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
          <div class="naranjaTitu">PRESUPUESTO <span class="pull-right"> {{ $presupuesto->fecha }} </span></div>
          <div class="naranjaSub"> {{ $presupuesto->persona }} </div>
          <div class="importe"> {{ $presupuesto->total }} </div>
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="{{$presupuesto->id}}" class="borrar_dato borrar_Naranja"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></a>
      </div>
   @endforeach
```

**El AJAX para hacer la actualización que lo mandamos a una ruta**

```
$(function()
  {
    $(".borrar_Naranja").click(function()
    {
      let url = "{{route('admin.actua', $presupuesto->id )}}";
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var informacion = 'id=' + id;
      if(confirm("¿Seguro que quieres marcarla como leida?"))
        {
          $.ajax({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
          type: "PUT",
          url: url, 
          data: informacion,
          success: function(){}
          });
          $(this).parents(".dato_Naranja").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
          .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
          //toastr["warning"]("Notificación vista", "Mensaje")
        }
       return false;
       });
  })
```

**Aquí la ruta**

```
Route::put('/admin/actua/{id}', function ($id){
        $presu = Presupuesto::findOrFail($id);
        $presu->status = 1;
        $presu->save();
    })->name('admin.actua');
```

Bien, me hace el cambio de estado en la tabla de manera correcta y sin problemas, pero cuando en esa tabla no hay ninguna fila con `status=0` me devuelve erro y no puedo ver ni la página.

**Me devuelve error aquí**

```
let url = "<?php echo e(route('admin.actua', $presupuesto->id )); ?>";

Undefined variable: presupuesto
```

Comment: La solución va en la zona de respuestas por favor

Comment: So lo se @BetaM pero queria saber si está bien antés de publicarla, pero tienes razón

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado de está forma, pero no se es la correcta. Ahora si me detecta la `id` de forma correcta y no me devuelve el error si no hay filas con `status=0`.

```
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var informacion = 'id=' + id;
  let url = 'admin/actua/' + id;
```